# Change button color on click - w/ React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I’m currently working on a code challenge in which I have to develop an interface for users to be able to submit their feedback. The issue I have is that when I click on one of the rating buttons, it doesn’t select the button, only when I click twice. And it always selects the first one.

For convenience, I deployed the project here: https://interactiverating-component.netlify.app/

And here's a fully working example: https://interactive-rater.netlify.app/

I’ve tried different approaches, some with best coding practices for React, but I didn’t succeed in finding the right logic to make this work. Below it’s the code for this part of the project.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import "../Styles/Rating.css"

//React 18.1.0
const ClientRating = (props) => {
    const rating = props.rating;
    //console.log(props, rating);

    const[Active, setActive] = useState(false);

    const changeColor = () => {
        setActive(true);
        if(Active){
            document.getElementById('badge').style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
            document.getElementById('badge').style.color = 'white';
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <section>
                <button className='badge' id='badge' onClick={changeColor}>{rating[0]}</button>
                <button className='badge' id='badge' onClick={changeColor}>{rating[1]}</button>
                <button className='badge' id='badge' onClick={changeColor}>{rating[2]}</button>
                <button className='badge' id='badge' onClick={changeColor}>{rating[3]}</button>
                <button className='badge' id='badge' onClick={changeColor}>{rating[4]}</button>
            </section>
        </>
    )
}

export default ClientRating
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're mixing react with manual DOM manipulation which is typically considered bad practice; you have multiple elements with the same ID, which is considered bad practice (element ID's must be unique)

Answer (score 0):

```
const rating = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => i + 1);

export const ClientRating = () => {
  const [selectedRating, setSelectedRating] = useState(null);

  const handleRating = (e) => {
    setSelectedRating(Number(e.currentTarget.dataset.rate));
  };

  return (
    <section>
      {rating.map((rate) => (
        <button
          data-rate={rate}
          key={rate}
          onClick={handleRating}
          className={"badge" + (selectedRating === rate ? " selected" : "")}
        >
          {rate}
        </button>
      ))}
    </section>
  );
};
```

and add appropriate styles for `.badge.selected` selector

---

if you don't want use data-attributes, you can also do it in next way:

```
onClick={() => setSelectedRating(rate)}
```

and then you'll not need `handleRating` function

Comment: While this may work, mixing React and manual DOM queries is still considered bad practice. Ideally, you'd be able to handle figuring out which star was selected before entering into handleRating. Then, passing into handle rating which star and then using react to determine the class name

Comment: @DerekPollard yeah, using data attributes in react is a somewhat controversial topic. added an alternative approach to the original answer